# Problem with setContentBorderThickness:forEdge: not actually setting the value

Tags: cocoa, nswindowcontroller

I'm trying to use `setContentBorderThickness:forEdge:` to create a bottom bar in a Cocoa application.

mipadi was on to something, but in testing it out, I think maybe this is a slightly different problem:

```
-(void) adjustContentBorderBasedOnArrayControllerSelection{
    if(([[self.resultsArrayController selectionIndexes] count] == 0)){
        [[self window] setContentBorderThickness:40.0f forEdge:CGRectMinYEdge];
        NSLog(@"%f", [[self window] contentBorderThicknessForEdge:CGRectMinYEdge]);
    } else {
        [[self window] setContentBorderThickness:60.0f forEdge:CGRectMinYEdge];
        NSLog(@"%f", [[self window] contentBorderThicknessForEdge:CGRectMinYEdge]);
    }
}
```

Both of those `NSLog()` messages show the thickness value is 0.0 even after I explicitly set it. Anyone know what's up with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By any chance have you checked to make sure [self window] isn't nil? Do you have your outlet setup right? I get that behavior if the outlet to the window isn't set.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`CGRectMinYEdge`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/CGRectMinYEdge). (On 64-bit systems, `NSMinYEdge` is `#define`'d as `CGRectMinYEdge` anyway).